# disabling move on left click in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse, right-click

It keeps happening, not too often but I always hate it, I accidentally move a file or folder to some random location because I was scrolling and the mouse went off the scroll bar and **BAM!!!** files start copying to another location. While undo usually fixes this, I would rather disable this altogether.

Does anyone know how to disable this. I'd rather use the right-click to move and have to press that on the copy/move/cancel dialog.

Comment: For me, this happens most when I am selecting numerous files in a folder (i.e., with `Shift`/`Ctrl`) and then I accidentally end up making a copy. Argh! So infuriating. It makes selecting files (especially hundreds) a very sensitive and agonizing task, and particularly dangerous when using a wireless mouse.

Answer (score 4):

Seems the best solution is to adjust the drag and drop sensitivity,

In XP it was easy, you could do it with Tweak UI, In Vista and Windows 7 you have to edit the registry to increase the drag and drop pixel sensitivity, I know of no way to disable it without other consequences.

This article is not for your exact issue but will have the same effect for accidental drag and drop.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/fixing-annoyances-stop-windows-from-copying-files-accidentally-when-ctrl-click-selecting/

Navigate to this key in the registry

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop

in the right pane you will see 2 DWORD values "DragHeight" and "DragWidth"

double click each of them and change the value to something from 10 to 20

What this does is increase the number of pixes you must drag a file or folder before it will drop it.

.

Comment: Nope this is not the fix the user us looking for... There is a simple registry tweak for this. It works with mouse button one. Regardless if you have your mouse defaulted to Left or Right hand use. The tweak this user is referring to only disables the drag and drop function for FIles and Folders within Explorer, but NOT the desktop.